# Event clicks on android CustomView controls - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, events, ecmascript-6

Im rendering a android layout.xml file on react native.while trying to implement events on views inside layout.xml on android.I'm not able to acheive it

my **customview.xml** layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height='40dp'
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/multipleCameraText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, Text View from Native"
        />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:height="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"

            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:height="40dp"
            android:text="Button 2"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

my **customview.java**

```
package com.typesproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.RCTEventEmitter;


public class CustomView2 extends LinearLayout {
        private Context context;
        public CustomView2(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
            this.init();
        }

        public void init() {
            //modified here.
            inflate(context, R.layout.customview2, this);
        }

        public void onReceiveNativeEvent() {
            WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
            event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
            ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
            reactContext.getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class).receiveEvent(
                    getId(),
                    "topChange",
                    event);
        }
    }
```

I want to implement button clicks on two buttons(button1 and button2) and change text inside text view(multipleCameraText).

my **customViewManager.java**

```
package com.typesproject;

import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class CustomViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<CustomView> {

    public  static final String Custom_View="CustomView";

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return Custom_View;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    protected CustomView createViewInstance(@Nonnull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new CustomView(reactContext);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how we can achieve separate events for buttons and textview.

Comment: you can try to put the view in the android activity or fragment, then in the react-native start the activity, instead of rendering it in react-native

Answer (score 0):

the layout view can not use in this situation. you have to define a class for the view, then use it in the ViewManager.
As for your situation, you firstly could define a class which extends `Button`,

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {}
```

then in the CustomViewManager expose the props and event

```
@ReactProp(name = "text")
  public void setContenxt(CustomButton button, @Nullable String text) {
    view.setSource(sources);
  }

@ReactProp(name = "text")
  public void setContenxt(CustomButton button, @Nullable String text) {
    button.setText(sources);
  }
```

as for the event, you can read [official API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android).

If you want to define a view that shows like the layout XML. the view have to extend Linearlayou or ViewGroup. that effect realizes is complex. the related
knowledge is the android custom view. you may have to override `onDraw`, `onMeasure`, `onLayout`.

you can look at the  `ReactViewGroup` class, it will give you some clues

Comment: Hi, I want to define a view that shows layout XML and add events for views inside layout xml. Let me know how we can achieve this.

Comment: @Kartiikeya In the end, I explain it. the layout XML can not directly be exposed to react-native. you can look at the ReactScrollView source code.

Comment: @Lenonard, I'm rendering custom view on React native. I cant able to add events for controls inside that view. Pls check my updated question

Comment: @Kartiikeya, you can realize it uses a react-native component, the react-native only supports the custom view which writes by code not XML. If you realize the XML effect, you have to handle too many things.